# How would I go about explaining the science of a world where everything is made of fabrics and craft supplies?

Tags: science-based, biology, fauna, flora

I'm working on a little project called Scrapbook Street where everything is made of fabric and or craft supplies, but while working on the world of the project, I've started to wonder *how* the world works. Some of my biggest questions are about the flora and fauna of the world; mainly the dominant lifeform of the project, the PatchPals.

The PatchPals are made from fabric, and their insides are all stuffing. Their eyes are buttons, which can blink and such. How would I go about explaining the scientific reasons for how these creatures are sentient? Another question would be on the crops, which are made of fabrics, just like the PatchPals, but grow with sun and water just like Earth plants. Would there be a scientific explanation for their fabric textures?

Comment: As per Willks' answer, you wouldn't .. it's fantasy, presumably children's fantasy, did you ever see Toy Story angsting over how to explain how Woody and the others can can think, talk and walk?

Comment: Hi StarreDragon, and welcome to Worldbuilding. Congrats on asking a better-than-average first question. Just so you know, it’s standard practice to wait at least 24 hours before picking an answer. There might be an answer that better addresses your question!

Comment: That sounds delightful. Do make this little project of yours become real.

Comment: When can I move into a home on Scrapbook Street??

Comment: @ribs@spare hah, we don't know, we're all struggling here on Scrapbook Street

Comment: The HumanPals are made of leather, and their insides are all meat. Did you ever wonder how a leather bag of meat can possibly be sentient?

Comment: No explanation is probably better than a bad explanation.

Comment: @user253751 I do not like that image at ALL

Comment: @StarreDragon then I hope you never go outside - there are eight billion of them!

Comment: Their biology isn't fabric and craft supplies, it just happen looks like that to us ... or maybe their biology is intertwined with fabric. (I think this could make for a useful answer, I just wouldn't know how to expand on that.)

Comment: @user253751 oh no, people, whatever shall we do

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**No need for science in a story like this!**

And you are in good company.

> “Who are you?” asked the Scarecrow when he had stretched himself and
> yawned. “And where are you going?”
>
> “My name is Dorothy,” said the girl, “and I am going to the Emerald
> City, to ask the Great Oz to send me back to Kansas.”
>
> “Where is the Emerald City?” he inquired. “And who is Oz?”
>
> “Why, don’t you know?” she returned, in surprise.
>
> “No, indeed. I don’t know anything. You see, I am stuffed, so I have
> no brains at all,” he answered sadly.
>
> “Oh,” said Dorothy, “I’m awfully sorry for you.”
>
> “Do you think,” he asked, “if I go to the Emerald City with you, that
> Oz would give me some brains?”
>
> “I cannot tell,” she returned, “but you may come with me, if you like.
> If Oz will not give you any brains you will be no worse off than you
> are now.”
>
> “That is true,” said the Scarecrow. “You see,” he continued
> confidentially, “I don’t mind my legs and arms and body being stuffed,
> because I cannot get hurt. If anyone treads on my toes or sticks a pin
> into me, it doesn’t matter, for I can’t feel it. But I do not want
> people to call me a fool, and if my head stays stuffed with straw
> instead of with brains, as yours is, how am I ever to know anything?”

[The Wonderful Wizard of Oz, Frank Baum](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55/55-h/55-h.htm#chap03)

Fantastic things belong in fantasy.  How do the Candy People ruled by Princess Bubblegum work, scientifically, being made of candy?  How do zombies get energy to move without breathing?  How does Goku lift an object thousands of times his own weight and not drive his own body into the earth like a tent peg?  How do Rainbow Dash and Minty pick things up, given that they have digitless cylinders at the ends of their forelegs?

It is ok.  It is fantastic!  Your world sounds awesome and very cute.  Except when I think of Coraline and the world where people have button eyes.  Then I get the willies.  Make up rules that are consistent for your world except when you break them in the service of storytelling.  Science can stick to greenhouse gas, and leave your crafty folk alone.

Comment: i like this quote especially: "“Of course I cannot understand it,” he said. “If your heads were stuffed with straw, like mine, you would probably all live in the beautiful places, and then Kansas would have no people at all. It is fortunate for Kansas that you have brains.”"

Comment: I read that superb paragraph of references and then for no reason I was putting it to The End of the World (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHa6a3FtPJg&list=RDEMYBtRUk0K_uQgVIrH6Mxdbw)
How are candy people working?/
Do zombies use ATP?/
Don't they know that the science is soft,/
Or maybe there's no science at aaaall?

Why doesn't Goku sink downwards?/
How do ponies hold their things?/
Don't they know that the science is soft/
And some of their tales are taaaaall?

Comment: "Make up rules that are consistent for your world" <-  herein lies the definition of science.  In short, if you violate the rules of your world for plot, then your world is presumably governed by magic, but if your world has consistent, immutable rules, then it is governed by science, even if some of the rules of that science are not the same as ours.

Comment: See also: *Little Big Planet*.  Similar aesthetic to *Coraline* which you mentioned.  There's probably numerous other examples, but these are standout ones.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Not quite, it's only science if they're naturalistic. For instance, rules about whose prayers get answered don't count as science. Nor do any other rules that invoke agents or properties that are social, moral, pertaining to narrative (think: tropes), or theological.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant  I suppose social rules would count as a 3rd group that can be neither science, nor magic, but all consistent, immutable rules are still science.  If a setting has a social rule that is immutable, then it would become a science in that setting.  For example, if prayer A always compels God to make B happen, then God would become as much a part of natural law as gravity and prayer as much a part of engineering as gears and levers.  I'm not trying to say all rules must be consistent, just that the rules that are consistent will define the science of your world.

Comment: No. I listed some other types in my previous comment. Terry Pratchett was fond of using tropes and narrative conventions as in universe laws, but they weren't science. Moral laws are obviously not science. Nor are theological laws; the Athanasian Creed is a detailed exposition of the Trinity which I subscribe to myself, but it's not science.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Science is actually only that which is derived by scientific method. Even things pertaining to natural laws that aren't found scientifically aren't science. Let alone things not pertaining to natural law. Theology, ethics, etc are separate in our world, and are in worlds we create.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant Then perhaps a more accurate statement is that any  consistent, immutable rule is the natural law of your setting; and therefore becomes the scientific explanation of things. Theological and moral laws are not natural laws in our world only because they are inconsistent and mutable, but a world governed a God that is consistent is indistinguishable from a world governed completely by natural law, and if writing about a Heaven like world, you may have a morality code baked into the natural law of the place to make sin literally impossible there.

Comment: @Nosajimiki God is real and eternal and his laws are the most consistent and immutable laws there are. They're just denied by some. Shall I mentally class you as a science denier? Or shall we recognise that there is a body of knowledge that's empirically testable using scientific method, and other bodies of knowledge where that is not so? You do realise scientific method is an actual process, right? And that not even all natural philosophy is science?

Answer (score 7):

### Fungal structures

While I'm firmly on the "don't explain fantasy worlds unless forced" bandwagon, "give the questioner what he/she asks for" is important too.

Fabric is ultimately a bunch of ordered fibres. In this case, these ordered fibres can grow and change and form more complex structures. Maybe the fabric is a complicated fungus growing medium? In response to water and sun, it's able to sprout more complicated structures.

This isn't a great explanation but it may be better than nothing.

It also explains why your house or at least your sewing room is probably full of loose threads despite diligent cleaning; the fungi are determined to replicate!

Answer (score 1):

The "fabric" is a phylum of plant or fungus.  Let's call it Fabricus.  [Moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moss) or [Lichen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) are the closest things I can think of; you can extrapolate from those a type of organism that produces colonies that look distinctly fabric-like.

Given this, PatchPals are a symbiotic relationship between species in phylum Fabricus and intelligent animals.  The "fabric" is the plant/fungus, and the "stuffing" is the inner animal.  Intelligent animals can have mushy consistencies sufficient to be stuffing, such as octopuses or jellyfish.

This has the additional benefit of explaining how "plants" work in this world.  Plants are just other species in phylum Fabricus that grow on their own and build rigid structures, rather than growing on the surface of an animal host.  Some types "plants" could actually be edible by members of the species (if that is desired).

Having this happen underwater makes this all more plausible, as that makes it much easier to have gelatinous animals.  Note that you can set it underwater without ever mentioning that it is underwater, as if water is everywhere, it is just the assumed surroundings of everyone in it (most people don't go walking around commenting on the air surrounding them on a regular basis).  Sure, movement works different underwater, fire is a lot harder, and you don't have weather, but those are all changes you probably need to make to have plausible land-based fabric creatures (I assert that land-based fabric creatures wouldn't do very well with fire, rain, or heavy winds).

Answer (score 0):

I think the two current answers are very good but I thought I'd give an answer that explores why you might choose one or the other. Which kind of comes down to some differences between fantasy and science-fiction, and the actual science of how living things, fabric and craft supplies are.

I think one way of understanding fantasy vs science-fiction is considering "magic" vs "mechanisms", where "magic" is essentially when the effect comes first, never mind how it came to be, and "mechanisms" are the situation where certain causes have certain effects and the cause always comes first. Think "magic love potion" vs "aspirin". A "magic love potion" *makes you fall in love* - that it's essential nature. The cause is very simple (you drink the potion), and the effect is nothing more and less than "a person is now in love with another". On the other hand, "aspirin" *is a certain molecule* - that's its essential nature, the collection of atoms it's made of. It so happens that taking aspirin relieves headaches, but that effect isn't fundamental to what aspirin *is* - in fact the aspirin molecule can have other effects, such as thinning blood, and the effects can change if the circumstances change, like if the molecule got degraded by heat or cold or if the body has a structure that reacts to that molecule differently.

So you can see fantasy as an aesthetic where you focus on effects first, and either want to give the explicit impression things don't have an internal structure that causes these effects, or you just don't want the reader to care about that structure at all. Whereas science-fiction is an aesthetic where things might have effects but you want to give the impression that all those effects have underlying mechanisms, like science tells us effects have underlying mechanisms in our world. (I like how this matches up quite well with David Eddings' definition of the difference, even though he was obviously biased - his definition, paraphrased, was "science fiction presents you with a watch and goes into deep detail into how it works; fantasy tells you what time it is and gets on with things")

It's not that magic systems cannot have internal structure per se, or that science-fiction cannot present effects whose mechanisms are so handwaved that they effectively don't exist. I think that's where the "aesthetics" part comes in. Compare how Star Wars (OG and prequels at least, I'm not up to date on everything) treats the Force vs faster-than-light travel. The Force comes across as a mystical, magical thing - the world is science-fictiony but that specific concept is presented as magical within that world. On the other hand faster-than-light travel comes across in the usual science-fiction way. It's not because of the detail the story gives in terms of mechanisms - the first movies and more so the prequels spend a lot of time talking about the Force, how it works, even injecting a "science mechanism" to underlie it in the form of midichlorians in the prequels, while faster-than-light travel is just there, it's not even explained or handwaved, it's as much an effect without a mechanism as anything can be. The difference is in *how we're supposed to think of those things* - the Force is fundamentally about humans doing things humans want and the thing "just happening". There are rules, but they're all around how humans want things and whether they should want them. The midichlorians are presented as a mechanism but not treated as such - when using the Force goes wrong it's not because that person's midichlorian count was low that day, it's because Luke felt conflicted and unsure about his goals or because desiring immortality is inherently ill-considered. On the other hand the faster-than-light drive, while it's never explained, it's shown to us *as if it's an engine*, and so we assume without having to be told that it must have mechanisms like engines do in our world. When the faster-than-light drive fails in the Millennium Falcon it's not because of deep issues about faster-than-light travel as a concept or because Han Solo didn't interact with the concept correctly, it's because there's a problem with the engine and Chewbacca needs to go back there and mess around with wires - fix the mechanism.

So I think the question for you should be, what vibes do you want to have? It sounds like you want more of a science-fiction feel - you want people to *think* that your animals made of fabric and stuffing move and breathe like real animals because of underlying mechanisms that make it happen, like real animals, and not "they're made of fabric and they're alive, period" like in Toy Story or Coraline.

The problem in terms of the actual science is that... there is no "scientific" explanation that makes your world work as presented. It's a bit like nailing jello to the wall - can you do it in this world? No, because of how jello and nails work. Can you imagine a science-fiction world where it would work? Well... you can certainly imagine a world where something called "jello" gets something called "nailed" to something called "a wall", but for it to *work* on a pure logic level you have to twist the meanings far enough to break. Like, you can make a science-fiction world where jello has the consistency of plywood, and you can use the word "jello" all you like but your reader will see that *it's actually plywood* and react accordingly.

The scientific reason your idea doesn't work is in the biology and physics of how life and fabrics and stuffing work. Life involves things doing things - moving, maintaining their internal state, perceiving the world, acting to achieve goals accordingly. These things are what in physics is known as "work", and in order for "work" to happen you need specific systems that capture and transform energy from outside the system to decrease the entropy inside the system by increasing it outside - meaning life *also* involves taking in energy (in the form of sunlight for plants, food for animals), having complex mechanisms to convert that energy into the various work the organism does, and expelling waste and heat. This is all stuff that requires extremely complicated internal mechanisms with many different moving parts, and the more flexible and interesting the things the living thing does the more complicated and varied the insides need to be.

On the other hand "fabric" and "stuffing" are simple things without a very complex structure, and it's hard to change that without changing their vibes. For example, "stuffing" is a thing that's shapeless and soft to the touch and reacts the same way whatever direction you poke it in... that *inherently* requires a certain lack of complex structure. Nobody ever used a car engine as a pillow, and while you *can* use an animal or person as a pillow it's kind of a delicate thing to do without damaging them or being uncomfortable because your head is on one of the hard bits. Similarly, "fabric" has more internal structure than stuffing but it's a very simple structure that makes a fairly simple, uniform material. That makes it very good for having the properties we want fabric to have, but very bad for making something act alive.

So with this I see three options for you:

- Go straight fantasy - your animals are made of fabric and stuffing, and they're alive, and that's it. It's a fantasy world or a magical element of an otherwise non-fantasy world, don't worry about it.
- Go hard science-fiction - you try and square the circle of how "fabric" and "stuffing" can have enough internal structure and complexity to allow things made of them to act alive. I think squaring this circle requires corrupting your "fabric" and "stuffing" until they have only the name and maybe only the most superficial appearance but they won't behave like our fabric and stuffing. But that can work fine if you only want some of the properties of "fabric" and "stuffing". I think the important thing there is to understand - **your animals will be basically animals (or robots, depending on how wet you make them), and the buttons/fabric/stuffing will exist in a very limited form**, like "they have hard, glassy eyes *like buttons* and their skin is soft and made of woven fibers *like fabric*" or "the process by which they came to be involved fabric but the end result transformed that fabric to the point it's basically living tissue/microprocessors" or whatever.
- Go soft science-fiction - like the FTL drive in Star Wars you give a *vague impression* that there's a mechanism there but handwave it hard. I think an important thing to understand here is that - **there is no science here**. You don't want actual scientific explanations, because actual science makes what you want impossible, you want something that *looks* like a scientific explanation. Something where the reader might think "I can buy that this is a world with scientists, and that this is something *those scientists* might say even though the scientists in *my* world definitely wouldn't, because that world plays by different rules". That's where AncientGiantPottedPlant's **"it's fungi"** idea can work; it associates something we know is alive with something that has some of the properties of fabric and stuffing. May I also suggest **"nanofilaments", "nanocarbon tubes", anything with "nano"**, which suggests a complex mechanism that's just at a scale smaller than the apparent simplicity of "fabric" and "stuffing". A hundred years ago you could have played with **"magnetism"**, a kind of mysterious force that can apply to anything and do everything. Heck, what about **"electricity"**? That's *quite* old-school in terms of "science-fiction handwave for life", it goes back to Frankenstein, but the fact fabric is inherently associated with static electricity makes it a really fun association IMO. Might work better for a humorous/retro soft science-fiction vibe in our 21st century.